# how to declare dataset in silverlight for windows phone7 using c#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Please  post the answer for how to declare dataset in silverlight for windows phone7 using c#?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for datasets in WP7. You have to build your own datacollections. (For example you could use the ObservableCollection).

My suggestion would be to check the [code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on the MSDN page. (The WeatherForecast example uses webservices to retrieve data).

Also I would suggest to read some on the MVVM pattern. ([MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153%28v=vs.92%29.aspx))

Comment: Thank you.could you post the answer for how to get the data from database  using webservices in silverlight for windows phone7 using c#

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Dataset you should use ObservableCollection to store your data (which you have read from your WCF or RESTful webservice) and bind it to your ListBox.

To lean more about how to bind listboxes I would say: create an empty "WP7 Databound Application" and see the default implementation it has.

Here is a good video tutorial about "[How to use webservices in WP7](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/Description.aspx?eventId=1878)"

Comment: Thank you.Could you post the answer for how to get the data from database through xml   using webservices in silverlight for windows phone7 using c#

Comment: I added new comments in the answer.