# Which control to use in Windows Phone 7 so i can display data from a webservice

Tags: windows-phone-7

i'm new to windows phone 7 and i have a webservice which returns data from a sql database.
I'm display the data in a gridview in asp.net.
Now i want to make the same in windows phone 7
Which control to use to show the records and how?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box datagrid control on windows phone 7.

This is because it is really hard to got a lot of data in a grid readable on a small screen as a phone. If you want to have this anyway you have to build your own.

You can use a listbox as some soft of grid like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock width="100" Text="{Binding Field1}"/>
            <TextBlock width="100" Text="{Binding Field2}"/>
            <TextBlock width="100" Text="{Binding Field3}"/>
            <TextBlock width="100" Text="{Binding Field4}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If this isn't what you're looking for you could maybe have a look at one of the following links:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-DataGrid-Control-for-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-Part-1.aspx

[WpfToolkit DataGrid does not work in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499527/wpftoolkit-datagrid-does-not-work-in-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox` with custom `DataTempale` is what you looking for.

First of all, download data from the server and put it into some collection. `ObservableCollection` is a best choice, because it's automatically update view when you add/remove new items. So, code snipped will be like this:

```
 ObservableCollection<CustomItem> items = new ObservableCollection<CustomItem>();
 // add items to the `items` list
 list.ItemsSource = items; // bind items to the ListBox with a name 'list'
```

Xaml:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="list">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDifenition Width="Auto" />
                          <ColumnDifenition Width="Auto" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text={Binding Field1} />
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text={Binding Field1} />
                </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply
When you saying "// add items to the `items` list" how to do that?
The webservice returns name, phone, address, city.
THANK YOU

Comment: It depends of what type server returns your data. If it `List<>` see `ObservableCollection` constructor. If it's not, probably copy items one-by-one.

Comment: this is the webservice
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetByName(ByVal mName As String, ByVal mCity As String) As DataSet 
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True") 
Dim commandString As String = "Select * From customers where CustName like '%" & mName & "%' and ( address like '%" & mCity & "%' OR city like '%" & mCity & "%')"
Dim myAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(commandString, conn)
Dim productDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
myAdapter.Fill(productDataSet)
Return productDataSet
End Function

Comment: `DataSet` is not supporter in WP7. Create another question or search answer elsewhere. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605912/how-to-declare-dataset-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone7-using-c